# Comparing OLS versus WLS residual standard error, is the smaller the better?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, least-squares, weighted-regression, generalized-least-squares

For a linear regression model I tried on a dataset, when I fitted OLS, the output is as follows:

```
fit = lm(price ~., data = art)

# Coefficients:
#                                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)                     2.326e+03  8.863e+02   2.625 0.008777 ** 
# temp_stagelate                  3.029e-01  8.735e-02   3.467 0.000544 ***
# temp_stagemature                4.009e-01  1.154e-01   3.473 0.000533 ***
# temp_stagemiddle                5.346e-01  8.646e-02   6.184 8.55e-10 ***
# temp_stagena                    1.766e-01  8.645e-02   2.042 0.041322 *  
# tonedark                       -4.306e-01  5.511e-02  -7.814 1.20e-14 ***
# tonelight                      -4.267e-01  6.214e-02  -6.866 1.05e-11 ***
# subjectflower-animal           -3.997e-01  6.972e-02  -5.734 1.24e-08 ***
# subjectlandscape                1.609e-02  6.429e-02   0.250 0.802480    
# size.square                     2.454e-04  1.696e-05  14.469  < 2e-16 ***
# size.sqq                       -6.205e-09  9.412e-10  -6.593 6.44e-11 ***
# coloringink and color           3.665e-01  5.522e-02   6.637 4.81e-11 ***
# further.inscribed.or.signedyes  2.997e-01  7.868e-02   3.810 0.000146 ***
# signedyes                       9.487e-01  2.058e-01   4.610 4.45e-06 ***
# inscribedyes                    1.865e-01  5.966e-02   3.126 0.001812 **
#   
# Residual standard error: 0.6806 on 1511 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.726,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7186
```

and when I tried to fit a weighted least squares (WLS) model,

```
gls(price ~. , data=art, weights = varFixed(~size.square))
```

the output is of the following:

```
# Standardized residuals:
#     Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
# -4.27128213 -0.58938641 -0.06659419  0.53758125  6.03938177 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                                    Value Std.Error    t-value p-value
# (Intercept)                    1851.4155  924.1690   2.003330  0.0454
# temp_stagelate                    0.3717    0.1020   3.645983  0.0003
# temp_stagemature                  0.6992    0.1257   5.563261  0.0000
# temp_stagemiddle                  0.4881    0.1032   4.729729  0.0000
# temp_stagena                      0.2973    0.0978   3.038328  0.0024
# tonedark                         -0.4489    0.0571  -7.867553  0.0000
# tonelight                        -0.4451    0.0627  -7.093028  0.0000
# subjectflower-animal             -0.3605    0.0716  -5.036949  0.0000
# subjectlandscape                  0.0625    0.0669   0.934295  0.3503
# size.square                       0.0003    0.0000  13.128687  0.0000
# size.sqq                          0.0000    0.0000  -5.179399  0.0000
# coloringink and color             0.4053    0.0560   7.235716  0.0000
# further.inscribed.or.signedyes    0.3425    0.0866   3.955705  0.0001
# signedyes                         0.8654    0.2979   2.905369  0.0037
# inscribedyes                      0.3211    0.0574   5.593102  0.0000
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.01437576 
# Degrees of freedom:  1511 residual
```

I get a much smaller residual standard error. I am wondering if the two residual errors I have are comparable, and if the smaller residual standard error in the WLS model indicates that the WLS yields a better fit?

Does a smaller residual standard error in general indicate a better fit?

Comment: May it be the case that for WLS you consider *standardized* residuals while for OLS you consider *raw* residuals? Then the residual standard errors may not be comparable.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure whether the function `gls` really does WLS, but you may know better. You could do WLS partly mechanically: `model1=lm(y~X); resid1=residuals(model1); weights=diag(resid1 %*% t(resid1))^(-1); model2=lm(y~X,weights=weights)`.

Comment: Thanks! But when I tried the procedure you mentioned above, I resulted in a much higher adjusted R-sqaure but when I checked the testing MSE, it is not getting any better. What could the reason causing this?

Comment: I wonder if you have tried the mechanical way of doing WLS? Are you getting similar results to those from `gls`? I am a bit suspicious regarding how `gls` works since it uses maximum likelihood estimation which is noever required in standard WLS or GLS...

Comment: OK, I see. But MSE of WLS is now larger than that of OLS, isn't it? At least that part will be right then. Regarding $R^2_{adj.}$, that is a good question! I tried it with simulated data and got very high $R^2$ and $R^2_{adj.}$ for independent data... This does not seem right. And that may merit a separate question.

Comment: So did you or did you not get larger MSE for WLS than for OLS? I am curious.

Comment: larger MSE for WLS

Comment: What is the average value of size.square ? What is its standard deviation ?

Comment: The lm function computes `sqrt(sum(fit$residuals^2)/df)` . The glm function computes `sqrt(sum(fit$residuals^2/sqrt(size.square))/df)`. Where `df` is the degrees of freedom of the residuals. For gls I do not know how to retrieve it but for lm you could use `fit$df.residual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RichardHardy says, Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) can be used when you can reasonably assume that your data is homoscedastic.  Weighted Least Squares (WLS) can be used when your data is heteroscedastic (but uncorrelated) and Generalised Least Squares (GLS) accounts for correlation and heterscedasticity.

When you compute `gls(price ~. , data=art, weights = varFixed(~size.square))` you are assuming heteroscedasticity without correlation.  Moreover, you assume that the **variance of each osbservation is proportional to `size.square`**.

The residual variance (the square of the residual standard error) obtained in the output of `gls` is **only the proportionality constant**, it does **not** contain the part that is proportional with `size.square`.

I don't know your data but you could try the following (i.e. WLS) and I think you will find the result of `gls` (see e.g. D.N. Gujarati, ''Basic econometrics''):

1. The intercept is to be replaced by a column vector $x_0$ with elements all equal to 1
2. replace all your independent variables $x_i$ by $v_i = x_i/\sqrt{size.square}$, also the $x_0$ that replaces the intercept;
3. Do the same for your dependent variable, i.e. $y=price/\sqrt{size.square}$;
4. regress this 'new' dependent variable $y$ on all the ''new'' independent variables $v_i$ using a model **without an intercept**, i.e. `lm ( y ~ v0 + v1 ... + vn - 1)`

Note: you weight each observation by $1/\sqrt{size.square}$ and then perform least squares (`lm`), hence the name ''weighted least squares''.

The residual standard error of the regression `lm ( y ~ v0 + v1 ... + vn - 1)` will be 0.01437 (see your example outcome for gls), so it is the resudual error after dividing each observation by $\sqrt{size.square}$ (and thus also after dividing the standard deviation by that value).

Answer (score 3):

Given the regressand ($y$) and the regressors ($x$'s), OLS will by costruction yield the lowest in-sample residual standard error among the linear estimators. After all, OLS *minimizes* the residual standard error (hence the term "*least* squares"). You should not be getting a smaller error from WLS than from OLS; it looks as if you are using different data for OLS than for WLS, which could explain the phenomenon. All in all, comparing OLS and WLS in terms of residual standard error is pretty meaningless -- you know the answer before you start the exercise.

The use of WLS may be justified if you believe that different observations have different error variances, i.e. $\text{Var}(\varepsilon_1)=\dotsc=\text{Var}(\varepsilon_n)$ does not hold. Then WLS may be more efficient than OLS (as long as you are able to obtain weights that are roughly proportional to inverse error variances).

Comment: I used the same data set thought, so I am wondering what is causing this situation...

Comment: What about `data = all` for OLS versus `data = art` for WLS? Also, could you report comparable results? Now the OLS output differs from GLS output. Perhaps try `summary` of one and the other.

Comment: it's a typo. I added the summary

Answer (score -2):

In terms of fit, both will give you the same estimates, so there is no difference.

In terms of inference, however, there will be. Smaller standard errors mean estimates are more precisely estimated. If you fish for stars in your regression table, then you should choose the smallest standard errors.

If you are more scientific, you will first ask yourself whether you should use a correction for heteroskedasticity at all. For that, you have a plethora of tests to run.

Comment: Hmm, how should OLS and WLS give the same estimates? $\beta_{OLS}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ while $\beta_{WLS}=(X'WX)^{-1}X'Wy$ where in general $W \neq I$; hence, $\beta_{OLS} \neq \beta_{WLS}$. This will also result in different fitted values, different model residuals etc.